# when to use explicit relations - schema design

Tags: graphql

I am pondering about schema design with regard to explicit vs implicit relation when to...

for example:
in an imaginary schema with 2 custom types author and post, each with several properties, A post type can reference an author in 1 of 2 ways:

1. explicit: having an Autor type property
2. implicit: having a scalar value that indirectly points to the author

when designing a shema. what should be my compass in this kind of desicion making?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

There's absolutely **no** value to the client in only returning the ID of a related resource when you could just expose a field that would return the entire resource. Exposing only the ID will mean the client will have to make subsequent requests to your service to fetch the related resources, instead of being able to fetch the entire data graph in one request.

In the context of other services, like a REST API, it might make sense to only return the ID or URL of a related resource. This is because in those cases, the payload is of a fixed size, so returning every related resource by default can quickly and unnecessarily bloat a response. In GraphQL, however, request payloads are client-driven so this is not a concern -- the client will always get exactly what it asks for. If the client needs *only* the author's ID, they may still fetch just that field through the `author` field -- while allowing a more complete `Author` object to be fetched in other requests or by other clients.

Comment: thanks for your respose.in some cases its not possible to have objects. for example, different services running on differetn nodes each exposing its own graphql schema. in that case, if one schema want to refference a type in another schema its not possible right? only through stiching/federation of sorts. am I correct in this thought?